# PyInstaller: How to uninstall own product?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to generate an own setup, which works pretty fine. Now I’m at the point to uninstall my own product and read the documentation about it, but don’t find any information about the topic. The open questions are:

- Is there any ‘build in’ way to generate an entry (in windows) in “Program and Features” section or do I need to manually generate registry entries?
- Is there any ‘build in’ way to easily generate an uninstall routine or do I need to build my own uninstaller.exe? (Or change setup to offers uninstalls option if it detect already installed product?)

Comment: AFAIK, All PyInstaller does is create an executable. The way the executable is installed/un-installed is left up to the user.

Comment: Maybe the name “PyInstaller” leads me to the wrong direction, though it is a tool to generate platform independent program installers. But I think your right, as mentioned on the homepage _“PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX”_

Comment: @ChristianDean: After spending so more time on the topic, I think you’re right. Please write you comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what PyInstaller and similar tools are used for; They are only used to create the executable. That is it. PyInstaller notes this on there [about page](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html):

> PyInstaller reads a Python script written by you. It analyzes your code to discover every other module and library your script needs in order to execute. Then it collects copies of all those files – including the active Python interpreter! – and puts them with your script in a single folder, or optionally in a single executable file.

If you want an installer or un-installer for your executable, you will need to use separate tools to create one.

Although not really accurate, it helps to think of PyInstaller as a "compiler for Python". If you have used other compilers before for languages like C++, you would know that they only produce an executable. They don't bundle the executable file alongside other things like an installer, because they are not part of the main executable application.

Note however, [there are ways out there for creating installers/uninstallers](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+make+an+uninstaller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=active&channel=fs&q=how+to+make+an+installer+for+windows). You simply need to use the right tools and methods for the job.